# Как отправить всем подключенным информацию о изменении объекта?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Есть consumer который обрабатывает подключения по веб сокету:

```
class BoardConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.board_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['board_id']

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.board_id,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.board_id,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        await self.send(text_data)
```

B есть view, которая позволяет поменять название board с определенным id:

```
def change_board_name(request, board_id):
    board = Board.object.get(pk=board_id)
    board.name = request.POST.get('new_name')
    board.save()
    # отправить инфу всем кто подключен по веб сокету
    return redirect(request.path)
```

Как отправить информацию о новом имени этой доски все тем, кого я добавлял в эту группу self.channel_layer.group_add(
self.board_id,
self.channel_name
)
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в BoardConsumes доопределить:

```
class BoardConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def board_message(self, event):
        await self.send(event['message'])
```

и тогда во view можно сделать так:

```
def change_board_name(request, board_id):
    board = Board.object.get(pk=board_id)
    board.name = request.POST.get('new_name')
    board.save()
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(str(board_id), {
        'type': 'board.message',
        'message': "test",
    })
    return redirect(request.path)
```